# directive to be used to include viewmodel in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have gone through the MVC3 tutorial for displaying the related data in asp.net page.
It has a viewmodel:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using ContosoUniversity.Models; 

namespace ContosoUniversity.ViewModels 
{ 
    public class InstructorIndexData 
    { 
        public IEnumerable<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; } 
        public IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; } 
        public IEnumerable<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

and a controller, with actions:

```
using ContosoUniversity.ViewModels;

public ActionResult Index(Int32? id, Int32? courseID) 
{ 
    var viewModel = new InstructorIndexData(); 
    viewModel.Instructors = db.Instructors 
                              .Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment) 
                              .Include(i => i.Courses.Select(c => c.Department)) 
                              .OrderBy(i => i.LastName); 

    if (id != null) 
    { 
        ViewBag.InstructorID = id.Value; 
        viewModel.Courses = viewModel.Instructors.Where(i => i.InstructorID ==         id.Value).Single().Courses; 
    } 

    if (courseID != null) 
    { 
        ViewBag.CourseID = courseID.Value; 
        viewModel.Enrollments = viewModel.Courses.Where(x => x.CourseID ==  courseID).Single   ().Enrollments; 
    } 

    return View(viewModel); 
}
```

when i tried in MVC4 it is such that **using ContosoUniversity.ViewModels;** is not existing

and at

```
viewModel.Courses = viewModel.Instructors.Where(i => i.InstructorID ==            id.Value).Single().Courses;
```

it is getting error as cannot convert viewmodel.instructors to `IEnumerable<viewmodel.Instructors>`

Comment: Please take care when you're formatting your code for us to look at. Without proper indentation, it's very hard to deduce scope and structure. =)

Comment: please leave some response.